# Changing the output a bit

Tags: python, list

Question is:

```
voting_borda:
```

(list of list of str) -> tuple of (str, list of int)

The parameter is a list of 4-element lists that represent rank ballots for a single riding.

The Borda Count is determined by assigning points according to ranking. A party gets 3 points for each first-choice ranking, 2 points for each second-choice ranking and 1 point for each third-choice ranking. (No points are awarded for being ranked fourth.) For example, the rank ballot shown above would contribute 3 points to the Liberal count, 2 points to the Green count and 1 point to the CPC count. The party that receives the most points wins the seat.

Return a tuple where the first element is the name of the winning party according to Borda Count and the second element is a four-element list that contains the total number of points for each party. The order of the list elements corresponds to the order of the parties in PARTY_INDICES.

This is my code:

```
def voting_borda(*args):
results = {}
for sublist in args:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if sublist[i] in results:
            results[sublist[i]] += 3-i
        else:
            results[sublist[i]] = 3-i

winner = max(results, key=results.get)
results_sort = sorted(results,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
return winner, results_sort
```

However, if i try

```
voting_borda(['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'],['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN'])
```

I get,

```
('GREEN', {'NDP': 4, 'CPC': 3, 'GREEN': 6, 'LIBERAL': 5})
```

But, I want the first parameter to be the winner(that part is fine), and the second parameter to be just the values and also to be in the order of PARTY_INDICES which is 
`PARTY_INDICES = [NDP_INDEX, GREEN_INDEX, LIBERAL_INDEX, CPC_INDEX]`.

any solutions or ways that i could make this better?

Comment: Either this is homework or [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546205/how-to-shorten-this-code-without-using-bunch-of-if-statements/) beat you to it.

Comment: Lots of you in the same class.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505169/how-to-append-the-number-of-item-frequencies-in-a-list-in-python-3-2/13505225#13505225

Comment: ive done that one already! but this question is differnet from that one

Comment: Haha, here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637068/been-stuck-on-this-for-3-hours-voting-approval#comment18707069_13637068

Comment: yeah.. our profs arent that helpful this year.

Comment: I think he's gonna know something's up when you all show up with the same answer but none of you understand it. PS [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542458/how-to-give-points-for-each-indices-of-list)

Comment: Could you help me or give me a hint into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The index thing (NDP_INDEX etc.) is really unnecessary and un-pythonic. Just use the string, and if you need to sort it according to something, use lists of tuples.

```
 vv = [ ('republican',3), ('democrat',9), ('libertarian',73), ('green',-2) ]
 vsort = sorted(vv,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
 print(list(party for party, value in vsort))
```

You can do [something similar](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) to get your answer. Hate to do the entire assignment for you...

Comment: could you explain what key=lambda is, we havent learned that yet!

Comment: A lambda function is an unnamed inline function. `lambda x: x[1]` is equivalent to `def f(x): return x[1]`. It's telling sorted to sort the functions according to the second element of each tuple. (psst read the page I linked)

Comment: is there a simpler way? i am a real beginner, we havent learned reverse=True that either :*(.. this is frustrating

Comment: Well, it talked about that in the page I linked you (nudge nudge wink wink). reverse is a [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) that controls whether the sort is ascending or descending. And lambda is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms). It's gonna be tough at first, especially if this is your first language, but hang in there. Hey, at least you won't have any bad habits from C. :)

Comment: Yes, that is true. You could accomplish the same thing using the `reverse` or `reversed` function after the fact, but it's more efficient to go ahead and let the `sorted` function do its sort that way in the first place.

Comment: now i full understand what u are saying. however, i have edited the code, but now the output is , ('GREEN', ['GREEN', 'CPC', 'LIBERAL', 'NDP']). how do i make it so that it gives the values? :(

Comment: If you're using the `list(party for party, value in vsort)`, use value for party instead of party for party. Read it like a sentence- - "Make a list of the parties, for each party and value in my sorted array".

Comment: wait i have lost u again. i have edited my code. if i do that i get ('GREEN', ['GREEN', 'CPC', 'LIBERAL', 'NDP']). but i want the values