# changing the output

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the output a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638807/changing-the-output-a-bit)

Question is:

```
voting_borda:
```

(list of list of str) -> tuple of (str, list of int)

The parameter is a list of 4-element lists that represent rank ballots for a single riding.

The Borda Count is determined by assigning points according to ranking. A party gets 3 points for each first-choice ranking, 2 points for each second-choice ranking and 1 point for each third-choice ranking. (No points are awarded for being ranked fourth.) For example, the rank ballot shown above would contribute 3 points to the Liberal count, 2 points to the Green count and 1 point to the CPC count. The party that receives the most points wins the seat.

Return a tuple where the first element is the name of the winning party according to Borda Count and the second element is a four-element list that contains the total number of points for each party. The order of the list elements corresponds to the order of the parties in PARTY_INDICES.

This is my code:

```
def voting_borda(*args):
results = {}
for sublist in args:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if sublist[i] in results:
            results[sublist[i]] += 3-i
        else:
            results[sublist[i]] = 3-i

winner = max(results, key=results.get)
return winner, results
```

However, if i try

```
voting_borda(['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'],['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN'])
```

I get,

```
('GREEN', {'NDP': 4, 'CPC': 3, 'GREEN': 6, 'LIBERAL': 5})
```

But, I want the first parameter to be the winner(that part is fine), and the second parameter to be just the values and also to be in the order of PARTY_INDICES which is 
`PARTY_INDICES = [NDP_INDEX, GREEN_INDEX, LIBERAL_INDEX, CPC_INDEX]`.

any solutions or ways that i could make this better?

Comment: its just a postion. basically i want the order of my second parameter to be in [ndp, green, liberal, cpc]

Comment: output in a tuple of strs and a list of ints

Comment: ('GREEN', [4, 6, 5, 3]), in this way??

Answer (score 0):

```
PARTY_INDICES = ['NDP_INDEX', 'GREEN_INDEX', 'LIBERAL_INDEX', 'CPC_INDEX']
party_dic = {}

for i, item in enumerate(PARTY_INDICES):
    party_dic[item.split('_')[0]] = i

print party_dic

def voting_borda(*args):
    results = {}
    for sublist in args:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            if sublist[i] in results:
                results[sublist[i]] += 3-i
            else:
                results[sublist[i]] = 3-i

    winner = max(results, key=results.get)
    results = [v for k, v in sorted(results.items(), key = lambda x: party_dic[x[0]])]
    return winner, results


print voting_borda(['GREEN','NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'],['GREEN','CPC','LIBERAL','NDP'],['LIBERAL','NDP', 'CPC', 'GREEN'])


{'NDP': 0, 'CPC': 3, 'GREEN': 1, 'LIBERAL': 2}
('GREEN', [4, 6, 5, 3])
```

Comment: but party_indice is a constant. PARTY_INDICES = [NDP_INDEX, GREEN_INDEX, LIBERAL_INDEX, CPC_INDEX]. i cant change it :(((((((

Comment: ahh? What do you mean? We can't make it dict?

Comment: i mean we can.. but is there a way to solve this without making it? and still have the output in order of ndp,green,liberal,cpc?

Comment: i must know the index of the parties by some way. are you sure the indices = [strs] or indices = [obj]

Comment: # A dict where each key is a party name and each value is that party's index.
NAME_TO_INDEX = {
  'NDP': NDP_INDEX,
  'GREEN': GREEN_INDEX,
  'LIBERAL': LIBERAL_INDEX,
  'CPC': CPC_INDEX
}

Comment: that is to say, you have a index list in advance?

Comment: yupppp yes i will edit it sec.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i have no skype account... you can make another question in stackoverflow. ps: i'm very sorry that my english is so poor that i can't comunicate with you smoothly~~-_-